# Unable to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to learn JSP and servlets by making a project. My goal is NOT to focus on JPA, ORM and persistence
or even EJB for now. So, please do not tell me to read a tutorial or book on that. Unfortunately, I am not supposed 
to use SQL queries to interact with the database. Instead, I used pre-written JPA code to manage the persistence 
while I focus on jsp and servlets.

When I run my project, I get the error -  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName AffableBeanPU.` 
**My project is located at -** https://github.com/double-whammy/affablebean.git
Download as zip button is on bottom right corner.

**Note** - My persistence.xml file IS inside the META-INF folder. I checked and built my project again. 
So that reason can be ruled out.

I googled and none of the solutions were of help. How do I fix this error ?

```
MyProject
|
|__java (src folder)
|    |
|    |__controller (package)
|    |   |__ControllerServlet.java
|    |
|    |__entity (entity classes here) 
|    |__session (facade classes for each entity class)
|
|   
|__WebContent
    |
    |__WEB-INF
         |
         |__view
         |    |__category.jsp        
         |    |
         |    |etc...
         |
         |__index.jsp
```

Exception:

```
Time|Info: Redirecting to /index.jsf
Time|Info: Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...
Time|Warning: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CategoryFacade, 
method: public java.util.List session.AbstractFacade.findAll()
Time|Warning: javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.findAll(Unknown Source)
at session.__EJB31_Generated__CategoryFacade__Intf____Bean__.findAll(Unknown Source)
at controller.ControllerServlet.init(ControllerServlet.java:31)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1212)
etc ................................................... etc...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName AffableBeanPU
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerWrapper.java:834)
at session.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
etc ................................................... etc...
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 33 more

Time|Severe: WebModule[/AffableBean]StandardWrapper.Throwable
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
etc ................................................... etc...
at session.__EJB31_Generated__CategoryFacade__Intf____Bean__.findAll(Unknown Source)
at controller.ControllerServlet.init(ControllerServlet.java:31)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1212)
etc ................................................... etc...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName AffableBeanPU
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerWrapper.java:834)
at session.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:41)
etc ................................................... etc...
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 33 more

Time|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[ControllerServlet]: Allocate exception for servlet ControllerServlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName AffableBeanPU
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerWrapper.java:834)
at session.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
etc ................................................... etc...
```

Persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="AffableBeanPU"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/affablebean</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you have Datasource jdbc/affablebean correctly set up on your server? This problem might be related to that. Try injecting just data source, and see if you can get connection.

Comment: @Gas - yes, the data source was set up correctly. I actually ran sql queries inside a JSP using my data source. After that,
I was supposed to replace SQL with with EJB code and that is when the problems started.  I wanted to focus mainly
on jsp and servlets and now I am forced to learn EJB which is almost a dead tech.

Comment: what servlet container are you deploying this to?

Comment: @anon - my container is glassfish4

Comment: Very similar code is working in Liberty using OpenJPA, so there must be some problem in your app or server. Maybe try to remove call to findAll from init(), and put it in doGet for test.

Comment: @Gas - did you run my code on a different environment ?  I will try what you said and get back. Thanks.

Comment: I did not run your code, but very similar. I dont have time get and setup your code.

Comment: @Gas - Is it possible for you to modify your setup or replicate my setup ? Thanks,

Comment: No, but you can download Liberty from here https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/ and try if the same problem will appear there.

Comment: @Gas - quick question. What is liberty ? That page does not make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: Liberty is a lightweight application server, a bit like Tomcat, but easier to manage and with many plug-able features like JPA, JSF, EJB Lite etc. Depending whether you use Eclipse you can either download plugin or stand-alone server. Check these: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/introducing_the_liberty_profile/  and this http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248076.html?Open

Comment: I am guessing that the whole mess occurred because I simply added persistence.xml to meta-inf without adding any persistence provider jars to my project. But, that should have given me a class definition not found exception instead. Anyway, once I am done with a couple of more questions, I will convert my project to EJB and see if my question's error is replicated.

Answer (score 15):

The `/META-INF/persistence.xml` must end up in runtime classpath, not in web resources. So, you need to put it in Java source folder, not in Web content folder. The `persistence.xml` is not related to web resources, but to Java beans.

Move it up:

```
MyProject
 |-- java (src folder)
 |    |-- controller
 |    |    `--ControllerServlet.java
 |    |-- entity
 |    |-- session
 |    `-- META-INF
 |         `-- persistence.xml <-- Here.
 `--WebContent
     `-- WEB-INF
          |-- view
          |    |-- category.jsp        
          |    `-- etc..
          `-- index.jsp
```

This way the build will produce the proper WAR structure with `/META-INF/persistence.xml` inside `/WEB-INF/classes`. You seem to be using Eclipse, you can also achieve this by selecting the JPA facet in project's properties.

[image]

This way Eclipse will generate a `persistence.xml` at the right place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Balus. I did not face this issue again because I started developing on a new system. In the new sys, I googled like crazy and found that you need to use JPA facets. Not sure if that was the reason my project worked. Did not reproduce the error. I got past the error in this question and got many other nasty errors. I am now developing the same code using netbeans, the original IDE for the tutorial. So far, its working perfectly.

Comment: As answered, the `/META-INF/persistence.xml` has to end up in runtime classpath, not in web resources. Your problem is caused because you had it in the web resources. When using the JPA facet (or manually creating the folder and filter at the right place), then it ends up in the Java source folder, which ultimately ends up in runtime classpath.

Comment: I'm using Intellij 2018 and GlassFish 5(Paraya)in my project, I had created another folder by the name `resources` and placed it on same hierarchy level as `src` and I got this same error. I moved `/META-INF/persistence.xml` from resources folder and placed it inside `src` as @BalusC and it worked like a charm. But of course this was after making necessary configurations at the paraya server(that is, setting up the JDBC resources and Connection Pool).

Answer (score 6):

You mention that your `persistence.xml` is present in `META-INF`. If you're deploying this application as a `WAR` file, your `persistence.xml` needs to be packaged as

```
WEB-INF
 `- classes
     `- META-INF
         `- persistence.xml`
```

According to the [JPA 2.0 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html), section **8.2 Persistence Unit Packaging**:

> A persistence unit is defined by a persistence.xml file. The jar file
>   or directory whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml
>   file is termed the root of the persistence unit. In Java EE
>   environments, the root of a persistence unit must be one of the
>   following:
>
> • an EJB-JAR file
>   • the WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR file
>   • a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR file
>   • a jar file in the EAR library directory
>   • an application client jar file
>
> It is not required that an EJB-JAR or WAR file containing a
>   persistence unit be packaged in an EAR unless the persistence unit
>   contains persistence classes in addition to those contained within the
>   EJB-JAR or WAR.

Answer (score 2):

Because your project has incorrect structure.  Create two separate parts for ejb and web application then pack them into EAR or use CDI. 
JPA (which EntityManagerFactory is part of) simply not activated by container for your application.

For Enterprise Application:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32wpTh1TmY4

For CDI:

http://www.hascode.com/2011/02/creating-a-sample-java-ee-6-blog-application-with-jpa-ejb-cdi-jsf-and-primefaces-on-glassfish/

Comment: What do you mean by ` Create two separate parts for ejb and web application then pack them into EAR or use CDI.` ? Please tell me what are Enterprise app and CDI and what are the differences. These things are new to me. The tutorial from which I made my code mentions nothing about this. My project structure is according to the tutorial. Not sure if that is causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: To be simple - just create new enterprise project in Netbeans/Eclipse and see what will be generated. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/figures/overview-applicationModule.gif

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Embedded Glassfish server, caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName cis_ejbPU
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:132)
```

TO RESOLVE IT I DID THE FOLLOWING

1) In the pom.xml  add the following dependencies

```
      <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                <version>3.2-b06</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
                </dependency>
```

2) Set up the HashMap properties for the embedded container

```
    File target = prepareModuleDirectory();
             Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, target);

             properties.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.installation.root", "./src/test/glassfish/");
             properties.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.configuration.file", "./src/test/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml");
    container = javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
```

3)

```
        private static final String MODULE_NAME = "embedded";
        private static final String TARGET_DIR = "target/" + MODULE_NAME;


    private static File prepareModuleDirectory() throws IOException {
        File result = new File(TARGET_DIR);
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("target/classes"), result);
        FileUtils.copyFile(new File("target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml"),
                new File(TARGET_DIR + "/META-INF/persistence.xml"));
        return result;
    }
```

4)  create the folder structure under

```
src\test\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
```

and copy the glassfish domain.xml which is present under

```
<glassfish server install> glassfish\domains\domain1\config  to src\test\glassfish\domains\domain1\config.
```

I followed the above steps to resolve the issue.