# Using A Servlet with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my JSP

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/example.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id='messagesDiv'></div>
<input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Name'>
<input type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Message'>
<script>
    var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://shining-fire-5148.firebaseio.com/');
    $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var address1 = $('#nameInput').val();
            var address2 = $('#messageInput').val();
            myDataRef.push({Address1: address1, Address2: address2});
            $('#messageInput').val('');
        }
    });
    myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        displayChatMessage(message.Address1, message.Address2);
    });
    function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
        $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
        $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller
package controller;

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@WebServlet("/test.jsp")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
            response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        DateFormat dateFormat;
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(request.getParameter("format"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss");
        }
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());

        request.setAttribute("date",date);
//        request.getRequestDispatcher("/messages.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

The controller completely removes everythign from my page, why? I just want to pass into it the date variable so that on my jsp i can call ${date}...how do I write the servlet to not remove everything existing on the page?

Comment: Please explain the desired flow of your application.

Comment: why does the urlpattern in `@WebServlet("/test.jsp")` is `test.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,

> The controller completely removes everythign from my page, why?

instead of

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/messages.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

use [RequestDisplatcher.include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/messages.jsp").include(request, response);
```

From the [`forward`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) javadoc,

> Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server. This method allows one servlet to do preliminary processing of a request and another resource to generate the response.

Compared to the `include` javadoc,

> Includes the content of a resource (servlet, JSP page, HTML file) in the response. In essence, this method enables programmatic server-side includes.

Comment: Hi Eliott. I have a question in java ee. I was wondering if you could help me. I don't have enough points to put a sufficiently attractive bounty. It is at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892866/unable-to-fix-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-retrieve-entitymanagerf

Comment: @james I glanced at it. I don't usually use glassfish, and you haven't posted *any* of your code but have 3 up-votes so well done. Be patient. Someone who can answer will look at it eventually, maybe.

Comment: There is complete code in the github link in the question. Please tell me if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: @james I gathered that. Doesn't seem on-topic to me because you haven't posted any code here and it certainly isn't a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as posted.