# Parsing a string with letters and numbers

Tags: java, parsing

Running this method gives a string of total post output

```
String numberOfPost = test.runNewAdvancedSearch(query, waitTime, startDate, endDate, selectedBrowser, data1, "");

int numberOfPostsInt = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPosts.replace(",", ""));
```

this parseInt does not work

How do I parse this out below?

```
"Total Posts: 5,203"
```

Comment: What does `numberOfPost` contain?

Comment: Will `numberOfPost` always contain a String of the form `Total Posts: x,xxx"?

Comment: Try my code, it is quite powerful and simple.

Comment: that is the string it results in "Total Post:XXXX"

Answer (score 4):

Try this fully functional example:

```
public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "Total Posts: 5,203";
        s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

Meaning of the regex pattern `[^0-9]+` - Remove all characters which occurs one or more times `+` which does NOT `^` belong to the list `[ ]` of characters `0` to `9`.

Comment: Do Integer.parseInt(s) to get your string as an int.

Answer (score 2):

if comma is decimal separator:

```
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1).replace(",", "."));
```

if comma is grouping separator:

```
    long d = Long.parseLong(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1).replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: If you like my answer, can you give me +1 ? Would appreciate it. I need points to make a bounty for an EJB question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892866/unable-to-fix-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-retrieve-entitymanagerf

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
String numberOfPost = test.runNewAdvancedSearch(query, waitTime, startDate, endDate, selectedBrowser, data1, ""); // get the parse string "Total Posts: 5,203
int index = numberOfPost.lastIndexOf(":");
String number = numberOfPost.substring(index + 1);
int numOfPost = Integer.parseInt(number.replace(",", "").trim());
System.out.println(numOfPost); // 5203enter code here
```